# Hover delay / Hover effect staying true after cursor leaving area of effect

Tags: html, css, hover

I have started making this webpage with a hover menu of flags ment for changing language of my webpage.

there are three flags displayed. This is a hover where the danish and german flag will only appear when i hover over the british flag.

This however creates a problem because there is a gab between the flags of 10 pixels. and as soon as the cursor leaves the british flag then the hover menu disapears. I need some kind of delay that will make the hover effect stay true for 1-2 sec after the cursor leaves area of effect. So that i can reach the danish and german flag.

My Html Code:

```
<div id="nav"> 
<ul style="list-style:none;">
<li><img id="England" src="England.png">
<ul style="list-style:none;">   
<li><img id="Denmark" src="Denmark.png"></li>
<li><img id="Germany" src="Germany.png"></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

My CSS code:

```
#nav ul li:hover ul{
display: block;

}

#nav ul ul{
display: none;

}

#England{
image-size:absolute;
height:60px;
width:86px;
position: absolute;
top:10px;
left:524px;
}

#Denmark{
image-size:absolute;
height:60px;
width:86px;
position: absolute;
top:80px;
left:524px;
}

#Germany{
image-size:absolute;
height:60px;
width:86px;
position: absolute;
top:150px;
left:524px;
}
```

I have tried using transition-delay:1s; but without luck. 
is there any brilliant minds out there that can help me out?

Comment: That is something that is tottally irelavant and something i have now removed from my code since you now made me aware of this. However they did this in a tutorial that is was following so thats why i did it! never again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is not to position all the the list items individually but rather the grouping of them in the parent `ul`.

By applying `position:absolute` and `top:100%`, the submenu will always be below the parent `li` **without any gap** *regardless* of how tall the parent `li` is.

```css
* { /* quick reset */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#nav{ /* just for spacing in demo */
    padding: 25px;
}
#nav > ul > li {
    position: relative; /* positioning context */
    background: lightgreen;
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    background: orange;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    <ul style="list-style:none;">
        <li>Flags
            <ul style="list-style:none;">
                <li>England</li>
                <li>Denmark</li>
                <li>Germany</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Absolute positioning is a very poor layout method and should only be used for specific effects. It has its place but nudging every element into exactly the right spot isn't it. This might help [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: well you actually came up with the solution though i had to make some changes to your code in order to make it do what i wanted it to do. 

That is i removed your padding: 25px; and replaced it with the intended position. 

then the background colors i changed to transparent.

lastly i i changed the html to: 

<div id="nav">
<ul style="list-style:none;">
<li><img id="England" src="England.png">
<ul style="list-style:none;">
                
<li><img id="Denmark" src="Denmark.png"></li>
<li><img id="Germany" src="Germany.png"></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

Comment: so it is not exactly what you did but definitely inspired by you. so guess you hold the honor of finding the solution

Answer (score 0):

I tested this and it works for me :)

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ogwdgwew/

What I did was put all of the elements in a single ul, but added pseudo ::before elements to the Denmark and Germany flags so that they bridged the previously empty gap.

HTML:

```
<div id="nav"> 
<ul id="flags">
    <li><img id="England" src="England.png"/></li>
    <li><img id="Denmark" src="Denmark.png"/></li>
    <li><img id="Germany" src="Germany.png"/></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#England{
height:60px;
width:86px;
position: absolute;
top:10px;
left:524px;
}

#Denmark::before,
#Germany::before{
position: absolute;
width: 86px;
height: 10px;
content: "";
top: -10px;
}

#Denmark{
height:60px;
width:86px;
position: absolute;
top:80px;
left:524px;
display: none;
}

#Germany{
height:60px;
width:86px;
position: absolute;
top:150px;
left:524px;
display: none;
}
#flags{
list-style: none;
}

#flags:hover *{
display: block;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry i have tried this now and it doesn't work for me :/ 

I have the exact some result as my own code with this. The flags hovers forth when i hover and disapears the second i go into the gap between the flags.

Comment: @user3677855 - have you deleted all the code you wrote and replaced it with what I wrote?

Comment: okay this is really weird. your fiddle works but when i paste your code into eclipse and run it in chrome it doesn't...... have you tried running yours in chrome ?

Comment: @user3677855 - I have chrome as my main browser and tested it and it worked!... This is really confusing

Answer (score 0):

Okay thx to all for helping me. it was without doubt you guys who inspired me to come up with a solution and this has been a very good learning lesson for me.

I came up with this solution for my problem:

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
<ul style="list-style:none;">
<li><img id="England" src="England.png">
<ul style="list-style:none;">
<li><img id="Denmark" src="Denmark.png"></li>
<li><img id="Germany" src="Germany.png"></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav{ /* just for spacing in demo */
position: absolute;
top:10px;
left:524px;
}

#nav > ul > li {
position: relative; /* positioning context */
background: transparent;
display: inline-block;
}

#nav ul ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top:100%;
left:0;
background: transparent;
}

#nav ul li:hover ul {
display: block;
}
```